# Fallback to alternative jumphost address upon primary jumphost disconnection

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, proxy, tunneling, connectivity

I have a subset of servers that I can only reach via a jumphost connection, for which I have two independent addresses to utilize. Normally, this is straightforward and either of the two jumphosts can be reached by including the following in my ~/.ssh/config...

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 240
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p <user>@<primary_jh_ip>
```

Where I could also replace `primary_jh_ip` with `secondary_jh_ip` and it would work the same way.

The issue I'm facing is that when connected to either of these hosts, I'm usually running scripts that can take a number of hours to complete. Occasionally, these hosts will "flush" all actively-connected users in order to clean up any that may have been left idle for more than 6 hours. When this occurs the downtime of said jumphost can be up to 10 minutes, which impedes any sort of automatic reconnection logic.

With this in mind, I'm hoping to find a solution where I can establish two simultaneous connections, one to either jumphost, and only send traffic through the primary. Then when this flush occurs, I can recognize the primary is no longer available, and instead redirect my traffic through the secondary instead. Redirected traffic wouldn't pick up **exactly** where the disconnection left off, but it would hypothetically be able to move on to the next available stage of my scripts.

Does anyone know of a way to do this, or if it's even possible?